# PHP domPDF - displaying rows from array

Tags: php, arrays, dompdf

I'm probably really overlooking something simple but this just won't work, I guess it's just me being stupid when trying to split the array.

Basically the below just gets the ID number, then selects the data from the DB. This works fine and the PDF prints at the end but there's no data on it.

If I change the **`json_decode`** to **`json_encode`** then it gives me just the first part of the array (but obviously it is not decoded so has some brackets and slashes where it shouldn't).

However I cannot get it to display all the rows. Can someone point out where I've gone wrong?

```
<?php
//etc etc
$idgg = $_GET['idgg'];
$query = "select * from `all_quotes` where quote_id='1493293451_1'";
if ($result = mysqli_query($link2, $query)) {
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$data = $row["data"];
$qdata = json_decode($data);
 foreach($qdata as $trow){
    $prods =  explode('|', $trow);
    $rowall = "<tr><td>$prods[0]</td><td>$prods[1]</td><td>$prods[3]</td>
    <td>$prods[2]</td></tr>";
   }
 }
}
require_once '/dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml('<table>'.$rowall.'</table>');
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("test.pdf");
?>
```

---

### EDIT

Array looks like:

["ABC|Lots of description here|31.12|ETC","DEF|Even more....|30.57|ETC"].

Also, I've noticed that if I don't use the `$_GET` (i.e. just input the `id` into the code instead) then I get the first result, but not the rest. Why on earth does that make any difference?!

Thanks in advance...

---

Updated code, added different mysqli structure. The above gives me the first row of the data (i.e. the first part of the array)

Comment: More an "out of curoisity" but why don't you serialize the array instead of building a full on text string?

Comment: @DanWhite No reason. If it's going to make it work I'll give it a try - just serialize it before I send it to the DB?

Comment: yes, **serialize($data)** and to retrieve it it's **unserialize($data)**

Comment: Thanks @DanWhite - it still just shows the first result though, and not the rest. It also still returns nothing if I use the `$_GET` as above code, I have to write it into the code manually.

Comment: I've got a funny feeling the one-row issue is something to do with the concatenation, does this not work with an array? If I change it around to work with `echo`, it works fine for all rows. However I can't put inline PHP in the domPDF `loadHTML` - it returns `500`

Comment: Look at the second line inside your foreach. Instead of appending to `$rowall`, you are resetting it to a new string.

Comment: @zenzelezz - OK thanks. How should it be instead? I tried `$rowall .= "<tr>";` but that returns nothing...

Comment: It occurs to me now that the primary reason for your problem is that you are not iterating over the entire result set, only the first row. See [example 2 on this page](http://no2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) for how you should use `mysqli_fetch_assoc`.

Comment: OK, I'll update the question but it's still just returning the first row only. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close to getting it right. You fixed the `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` issue, but when you did that you brought back the earlier error of overwriting the generated string. The correct loop, as far as I can tell, should be:

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($link2, $query)) {
    $rowall = ""; // Start out with an empty string

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $data  = $row["data"];
        $qdata = json_decode($data);

        foreach($qdata as $trow){
            $prods =  explode('|', $trow);
            // Here you were overwriting the string in each iteration, since you only used "=", not ".="
            $rowall .= "<tr><td>$prods[0]</td><td>$prods[1]</td><td>$prods[3]</td>
<td>$prods[2]</td></tr>";
        }
    }
}
```

If this still only gives one row, then run the SQL query directly in your database and make sure that it really does return more than one row.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much, works like a charm :) Just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try
First thing you should try the [link](https://www.functions-online.com/json_decode.html) and check whether your json object is correct

Check what json object are so that you know what you r dealing

Normally a json string when passed to json_decode it will return the object 
as for.e.g consider

```
 $json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';
 var_dump(json_decode($json));
/* output
object(stdClass)#1 (5) {
 ["a"] => int(1)
 ["b"] => int(2)
 ["c"] => int(3)
 ["d"] => int(4)
 ["e"] => int(5)
} */
```

whereas

```
var_dump(json_decode($json, true));
/* output
array(5) {
["a"] => int(1)
["b"] => int(2)
["c"] => int(3)
["d"] => int(4)
["e"] => int(5)
}*/
```

This return associative array which can the be used by you.

Or else I suspect the data maybe stored in serialized format for which you can use
[unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) function

Comment: Thanks @Rohit but it returns a correct array, it's just that it won't display any more than the first result. Yet if I replicate this in a normal PHP file and `echo` the rows rather than adding them to `$rowall`, it works fine. I just need it to work somehow with domPDF!